# Italic Cyrillic character display as tofu characters and other weirdnesses in LuaTeX using font EB Garamond

Tags: luatex, italic, cyrillic, ebgaramond, latin

For some reason with the [EB Garamond font](https://github.com/georgd/EB-Garamond/releases/tag/nightly), italic Cyrillic characters do not appear at all with LuaTeX, even though I have the italic font installed (and it supports Cyrillic) and it works in XeTeX.

Also, the Latin italics look slightly bolded in LuaTeX.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}

\begin{document}
Normal Latin: ABCDabcd

Italic Latin: \textit{ABCDabcd}

Normal Cyrillic: АБВГабвг

Italic Cyrillic: \textit{АБВГабвг}
\end{document}
```

**Using XeTeX:** (everything looks normal)
[image: Screenshot of output from the above code in XeTeX]

**Using LuaTeX:** (Latin italic looks bolded, Cyrillic italics don’t show up at all)
[image: Screenshot of output from the above code in LuaTeX]

Comment: add `\XeTeXtracingfonts=1 ` to the xelatex compilation and then check in the log-file which actual font files it uses and compare that with the fonts used by lualatex (they are list at the end of the lualatex log) .

Comment: `luatex` is taking the italic from the smaller optical size, which is less complete. Try `\setmainfont{EB Garamond}[SizeFeatures={{Size={-12},Font=*08-Regular},{Size={12-},Font=*12-Regular},},ItalicFeatures={SizeFeatures={{Size={-12},Font=*08-Italic},{Size={12-},Font=*12-Italic},},},]` with `\documentclass[12pt]{article}`.

Comment: @Thérèse Thank you! this fixed it!

Comment: @Thérèse - Please repost this comment as an answer.

Comment: The above comments are correct. In general. When you `\usepackage` it loads a sty file, which has its own font instructions.

Comment: @Mico No time now, but it’s not a complete answer since I don’t use `xetex` and don’t know why it behaves differently here. Is it grabbing the Octavio Pardo version from TeX Live?

Comment: @Thérèse - No, the OP is using the Georg Mayr-Duffner or "original" version -- the one without the bold font weight, but with additional glyphs that Octavio Pardo chose not to take on board.

Comment: @Mico `xetex` seems to move to the smaller optical size more reluctantly. If I add `\scriptsize` to the MWE, tofu appears even with `xetex`.